MUI: extending color issues
Here are my colors:
import { PaletteOptions } from "@mui/material/styles";

export const palette: PaletteOptions = {
    primary: {
      50: "#FFF5FA",
      100: "#FFEBF5",
      200: "#FED7EB",
      300: "#FCBADC",
      400: "#FC8CC6",
      500: "#FE6CB7",
      600: "#FD4FA8",
      700: "#C93B84",
      800: "#AD296D",
      900: "#8F1E59"
    },
    secondary: {
      50: "#FAFAFA",
      100: "#F4F4F5",
      200: "#E4E4E7",
      300: "#D1D1D6",
      400: "#A0A0AB",
      500: "#70707B",
      600: "#51525C",
      700: "#3F3F46",
      800: "#26272B",
      900: "#18181B"
    },
    error: {
        50: "#FEF3F2",
        100: "#FEE4E2",
        200: "#FECDCA",
        300: "#FDA29B",
        400: "#F97066",
        500: "#F04438",
        600: "#D92D20",
        700: "#B42318",
        800: "#912018",
        900: "#7A271A"
    },
    background: {
      default: '#FFFFFF',
      paper: '#AAA 2.11',
    },
    grayIron: {
      50: "#FAFAFA",
      100: "#F4F4F5",
      200: "#E4E4E7",
      300: "#D1D1D6",
      400: "#A0A0AB",
      500: "#70707B",
      600: "#51525C",
      700: "#3F3F46",
      800: "#26272B",
      900: "#18181B"
    },
  }


First question: it doesn't let me declare secondary color like this, it forces me to use primary, light and dark, why? It tells me MUI: The color (secondary) provided to augmentColor(color) is invalid.
The color object needs to have a main property or a A400 property, but my designer only provided me those tones.
I cannot use either grayIron.50 nor secondar.light as a color for my AppBar (it's not only a typescript issue), why?

EDIT:
I import this palette in my theme creation oviously:
'use client';
import { createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';
import { palette } from './palette';
import { typography } from './typography';
import { components } from './components';

let theme = createTheme({
  typography,
  palette,
  components
});

export default theme;



You'll need to supply your custom color palette to createTheme - creating a palette in isolation wouldn't work and wouldn't make your palette available for use in MUI components.
Referencing this section in the MUI docs, you might do something like the following:
import { createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';

const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    grayIron: {
      50: "#FAFAFA",
      100: "#F4F4F5",
      200: "#E4E4E7",
      300: "#D1D1D6",
      400: "#A0A0AB",
      500: "#70707B",
      600: "#51525C",
      700: "#3F3F46",
      800: "#26272B",
      900: "#18181B"
    },
  },
});

// In your top level file, where your theme provider is located, use your new custom theme:
<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>...</ThemeProvider>


I'm sorry, I'm going to update my message, I'm currently doing this, it's just that I import my palette form an other file in my theme creation.
